# Substitution in PDE (heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, substitution

Members,

i have a little question concerning the following subsitution for the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$.

The substitution is the following:
$$t = \zeta x^2$$
$$u(x,t)=x^cF\left(\frac{t}{x^2}\right)=x^cF(\zeta)$$

The author (*Baumann, 1999: Symmetry Analysis of Differential Equations with Mathematica*)concludes:
$$cF-c^2F+\frac{d F}{d\zeta}-6\zeta\frac{d F}{d\zeta}+4c\zeta\frac{d F}{d\zeta}-4\zeta^2\frac{d^2 F}{d \zeta^2}=0$$

It would be nice if someone could give me a step by step explanation for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-similar transform namely $\zeta = \frac{t}{x^2}$. This problem is just a case of book keeping.
$$
\partial_x = \frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\\
\partial_t = \frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial t}\frac{d}{d\zeta}
$$
we also have
$$
\partial_{xx} = \frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}
$$
now we have
$$
\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial x} = -2\frac{\zeta}{x}\\
\frac{\partial\zeta}{\partial t} = \frac{\zeta}{t}
$$
so we have
$$
\partial_x = -2\frac{\zeta}{x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\\
\partial_t = \frac{\zeta}{t}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\\
\partial_{xx} = -2\frac{\zeta}{x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\left(-2\frac{\zeta}{x}\frac{d}{d\zeta}\right) = 4\left(\frac{\zeta}{x^2}\frac{d}{d\zeta} -2\frac{\zeta^2}{x^3}\dfrac{dx}{d\zeta}\frac{d}{d\zeta} +\frac{\zeta}{x}\frac{d^2}{d\zeta^2}\right)
$$

Now with all these in place, I then suggest taking the derivatives with respect to the original variables but transforming $u$ i.e.
$$
u_t = \partial_t  x^c F(\zeta) = u_{xx} = \partial_{xx} x^c F(\zeta)
$$
thus 
$$
x^c\partial_t  F(\zeta) = \partial_x\left[cx^{c-1}F(\zeta) +x^c \partial_x F(\zeta)\right] = c(c-1)x^{c-2}F(\zeta) + 2cx^{c-1}\partial_x F(\zeta) + x^c \partial_{xx}F(\zeta)
$$
or
$$
\partial_t  F = \frac{c(c-1)}{x^2}F + \frac{2c}{x}\partial_x F + \partial_{xx} F
$$
now apply the transforms - then you are done.

Comment: @Chinny84: Very clear explanation! Thank you alot :). BTW i think in the line where you substitute u_t it should be $x^cF(\zeta)$.

Comment: Opps you are so right!